# How to limit AppSync queries for users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

AWS AppSync charges you for the # of GraphQL operations (each request could be a GraphQL query/mutation).
Is there a way to protect from malicious users that spam AppSync and GraphQL operations?
I.E., is it possible to limit the # of GraphQL operations per user (perhaps that every user has a quota).
Is it also possible to detect this type of user and ban them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AWS WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/how-aws-waf-works.html) (Web Application Firewall). [Rate based rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-rate-based.html) might be something that you can use.

Comment: Is it possible to use AWS WAF Rate Based Rules with AWS AppSync?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. AWS WAF can be deployed on Amazon CloudFront, the Application Load Balancer (ALB), Amazon API Gateway, and AWS AppSync

Comment: This only allows limiting by IP. Ideally a client's quota usage isn't tracked by IP. WAF is the best DDoS defense, but if you need to give different clients differing quotas, a different solution is needed